# food chemistry maltodextrin vs organic maltodextrin

Tags: food-chemistry

what is the difference between 'normal' food additive maltodextrin and "organic maltodextrin"? Is it only the primary source (i.e.: corn, wheat etc) that is organic or is it a different process to create maltodextrin? And is maltodextrin the same as food additive 1405?

Answer (score 1):

"Food additive 1405" refers to the process for the modification of starch; in this case the process uses enzymes to break up the starch molecules into oligosaccharides between 3 and 20 saccharides.

The difference between regular maltodextrin and 'organic maltodextrin' would be that the source was grown without synthetic pesticides and synthetic fertilizers. 'Organic maltodextrin' may also need to use natural enzymes.